# Testing S3 4xxErrors alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an Cloudwatch alarm to monitor the S3 bucket 4xx errors for specific bucket.
Alarm is created and in OK state.
I have python lambda where I am getting object from above S3 bucket using boto3 get_object()
I tried getting non existing object from the S3 bucket to simulate the 4xx error.
But inspite of getting NotFound error the alarm is not getting triggered.
Can someone please let me know how I can make the alarm trigger ?
Below is the alarm config -

Namespace: **AWS/S3**
Metric name: **4xxErrors**
Statistic: **Sum**
Period: **1 minute**
Datapoints to alarm: **1 out of 5**
Threshold: **4xxErrors >= 10 for 1 datapoints within 5 minutes**
BucketName: **<expected_bucket_name>**

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that

1. We need to Enable request metrics on the S3 bucket to capture the metrics.
2. Once enabled, alarm can be created on the metric filter.

I tested with above steps and it worked for me.